# AndroidStudio fails with internal exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I have seen a similar question here regarding this error but the given solutions do not fit to my problem.

I'm running AndroidStudio 3.5 (but without any FindBugs application or something like that which is mentioned in the other question) and stumble upon this error when I try to compile my App:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:85)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:232)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:148)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:363)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have the feeling - comparint to Eclipse - this new AndroidStudio is a hell of bugs - I always stumbe upon problems with Gradle, with the project configuration, with the installed packages and now during compiling.

So...anybody have any idea where this error comes from and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you also using flutter

Comment: @Bali: no - only the plain AndroidStudio as downloaded from Google and the plain API, no additional libraries

Comment: Same here, I've loaded a Java-gradle project and get this error when I try to run it from AndroidStudio